# Can't add items (neither layout) to activity (ADT)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, adt

I am new developing in Android. I am using ADT 22.3.0 (downloaded 10 days ago).
I open a new Android proyect and when finish and activity_main is open, I cannot add nothing to it, nor items nor layout. I have read that I need a layout to add items (and my activity doesn't have one) but I cannot add a layout neither.
**My project config:**
`minSDK`: 11
`targetSDK`: 19
I checked action bar.

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

And a [SnapShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozW60.jpg):

Comment: go to file- new- xml file- create

Comment: I'll try, but what is the problem? I would like to know to learn more about ADT

Comment: once clean ur project and build from the "project" menu and check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is (I think) that I checked horizontal swipe to move between tabs of action bar. This option creates a ViewPager instead a standard layout activity. I edited manually the XML to "insert" the ViewPager inside a global layout and now I can add (or move) items.
Here is the new code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="214dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.36"
    app:context=".MainActivity" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.11"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```